# Magento multi store remove add to cart from one store and show on others

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento multi-store website.
I have three stores.
I want to remove/hide the Add to cart button from one store. But the other stores should display it.

Can I do this from admin panel?
What is the easyest solution?

Comment: If you use different theme and handle it through .phtml that will be easiest.

Comment: it's a solution, but in the future I don't want to be obligated to change two-three themes when I make a change to the website..

Comment: you only have some specific part in your store associated theme and let other things come from a fall back theme.This will minmiza you multiple site template work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to use a module.
Now I can set from admin panel for each store (or website/global) to:

1. Show "add to cart" button and the price
2. Hide both
3. Show only "add to cart" button
4. Show only the price

And I can also set this settings to work for certain user groups.
There's no need for extra themes or some "hard code" :)
We need to work clean..

This is the Module (and it's free):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/hide-cart-price-5914.html

TAKE CARE: This module will probably not work out of the box.
When i installed the module it gave an error page with Class 'Zend_log' not found in Rule.php, this error page came up when i visited 'system -> configuration' and 'customer->IG Hide Cart and Price Rules' and in the frontend at every product.
well this is because of a bad name for a function in the Rule.php file.
my not creative solution was(because of the late time):
go to: /app/code/community/IG/HideCartPrice/Model/Rule.php
Find line 129: public function load($id)
Change it to: public function load1($id)
Find line 131: parent::load($id);
Change it to: parent::load1($id);

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

In your template you could check for the store id, for instance, if you don't want it to show in store id 3...

app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
...
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && Mage::app()->getStore() != "3"): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">[...]</div>
<?php endif ?>
...
```

And that should remove the add to cart for the product pages.

---

You could leave the button there but disable it's ability to be added to cart with a module that and overrides `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()`.  You could redirect the user and add a message saying that it's disabled, etc.

Comment: thanks, but this is "hard code".. I needed a "clean code" solution

Comment: This is the "easier" solution.  You could build a small module that will allow you to select in the admin panel which store's shouldn't have an add to cart buttons/not be allowed to add to cart (they could still hit the controller `checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]`).